# How to filter adobe rules in console tab?

Tags: adobe-launch

I have recently learned working on Adobe Launch. I wanted to know in the console tab on a webpage which rules are getting fired and which are not met. I used the launch and DTM Switch and it gave me the names of all the rules but I wanted them to be filtered. For example:- if I want to look at the rules that are being fired then rules which are not met should not be in the list.
Seeing the rules using launch and DTM switch is time consuming and error prone.

Can someone please help me with this thing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Firstly, a sidenote.. DTM Switch is old and no longer supported. Adobe's current tool is the [Adobe Experience Cloud Debugger](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/debugger/using/experience-cloud-debugger.html?lang=en).

Comment: Secondly, Adobe's debugger currently does not offer a direct/formal filter for this. However, if you look at the logs tab of the debugger, there is a search field and you can enter in "fired" and it will sort entries that have "fired" in them first, then the rest. This is about the best you're going to get ATM.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so 2 options to enable Adobe Launch Debugging in console.

First one is to type `_satellite.setDebug(true)` in the developer console.
Second is to install Adobe Launch command https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/launch-command/nkjhamgjeocefocmpbcjfmohkjgildki and switch the Debug switch.

In each case you will need to reload your page.

You will notice logs that are now present prepended by  in your developer console.
These are the Adobe Launch debug logs and the ones when you use `_satellite.logger.log`

To see which rules fired which means there met the event and conditions and actions was executed then filter by `fired` in your developer console.
You will see something like  `Rule "name of my rule" fired.`

You can also see the rules that did not fire for specific reason by looking at logs:
 `Condition "my condition name" for rule "my rule name" was not met.`

I would advise you to create tagging naming standards: https://dev.to/alcazes/adobe-launch-tagging-standards-3aak as it will help you read the logs.